# What can cause an input placeholder to hide?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I'm using Vuejs for a website, and I'm facing a strange problem.
 For some reason, the placeholder of an input is showed only when I reload the page. If I navigate through the website using vue-router, it disappears. I have to reload so it is visible again.

Note : there is other placeholders who are perfectly working on the same page (not the same component tho).

What can cause a placeholder to not be displayed?

I can't really show the code, because I think the problem is more about the whole app than a tiny bit of code, here is the input anyway:

```
<form action="/http://localhost:4000/search">
        <input type="text" id="InputSearchArticle" v-model="searchArticle" placeholder="Browse..." />
       <router-link :to="{ name: 'search', params: {searchArticle } }">
           <div class="search-trigger" @click="triggerSearch"></div>
       </router-link>
 </form>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: The placeholder only displays if no content is in the input.   is your: `searchArticle` variable containing any content other than the empty string?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, unfortunately it is only an empty string. Also, this component is used several times, can it be the issue?

Comment: I don't have any idea if this could be related or not, but: does the other `input` elements have a `name` attribute? Or is this the only one with no `name` attribute? Also, does this happen in every browser?

Comment: None of the inputs have a name attribute! And yes this happens in every browser...

Comment: I think we would need more insight.  Is there a way for you to develop a running sample for us to look at on something like: jsfiddle, etc

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the color of the placeholder is the same as the input's background color?